# AVRecorder is delay when back from background mode?

Tags: objective-c

i am using a lot the AVRecorder and AVPlayer.
i saw that they both , delay when i am back to my app ,after she was on background- then if for example i am trying to record , it takes 4 seconds till it starts .

in my code, i am preparing to record **before** i am recording, but when back to app, it doesnt help .

what can i do to improve it ?

this is done when app is open(at the start, not when back from background! )

```
-(void)prepareToRecord
{
    NSArray *dirPaths;
    NSString *docsDir;

    NSString *sound=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sound%d.caf",[memoryInstnace getNextFreePlace]];
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) ;
    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    currentSoundFilePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:sound];
    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:currentSoundFilePath];



    NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],                 AVSampleRateKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                              nil];

    NSError *error;

    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:soundFileURL settings:settings error:&error];

    //to not having a delay befor record
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];

    if (recorder)
    {
        [recorder prepareToRecord];
        recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;

    }
    else
        NSLog( @"error in recordings"  );


}
```

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If another app had grabbed the control of the mic via starting an active AVAudioSession, then iOS will fade out control from that app and give it to you when you activate your session.  This can take a second or two.  Is this what is happening? or is something else slowing you down?